# Kafka message key is null using Confluent.Kafka consumer library

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I am using Debezium to perform CDC against my DB to create messages in Kafka.  Using tools like kafdrop and OffsetExplorer I am able to see the message **key** and **value**.  However, from a .NET framework application, using the Confluent.Kafka libraries, when I consume the messages, the message **key** is always null.

How can I retrieve the message **key** using the Confluent.Kafka library?

Here is the code for the VS project:

```
using System;
using Confluent.Kafka;
using System.Threading;

namespace KafkaConsumer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new ConsumerConfig
            {
                BootstrapServers = "kakfa:9092,localhost:9093",
                GroupId = "foo",
                AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,
                
            };

            var topics = "CAC_connector.dbo.sessionLogs";
            bool cancelled = false;

            // Define the cancellation token.
            CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = source.Token;

            using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).Build())
            {
                consumer.Subscribe(topics);

                while (!cancelled)
                {
                    var cr = consumer.Consume(cancellationToken);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Consumed record with key {cr.Message.Key} and value {cr.Message.Value.Substring(0, 96)}");
                }

                consumer.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers,
Kyley

Comment: What did you expect `ConsumerBuilder<Ignore` to do?

Comment: I hadn't noticed that when copying the code from another example.  I was looking for configuration settings and didn't understand that constructor params.

Thank you for pointing that out to me.  When changing to `ConsumerBuilder<string` it is working as I would expect now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

As OneCricketeer pointed out, I was initially constructing the ConsumerBuilder to Ignore the key. When I changed the constructor to `ConsumerBuilder<string, string>` the key is included in the Message.